# Can I install and use two versions of a program?

Tags: apt, versions

Say I have an application and it has two versions, 1.0 and 1.1. 1.0 has much more features while 1.1 has a new design and better optimization. Is there anyway I can have both versions, 1.1 and 1.0 and I can switch between both of them or even use them simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the old-school world this is possible when you have installed deb-version of software along with self-compiled (inside `/usr/local` or in home-folder) or portable (extracted somewhere in the home-folder).

In modern world this is possible when you have installed application - for example Okular from [deb-package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/okular) along with its [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/okular) and [FlatPak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.kde.okular) versions:

- deb - `okular`,
- snap - `snap run okular`,
- flatpak - `flatpak run org.kde.okular` .

Some applications may be virtualized (QEMU, KVM, VirtualBox, Xen, VMWare and so on) or containerized (by Docker, chroot, schroot, LXC or similar).

Comment: Besides the answer: You could always use virtualization or install source versions in /opt/  using the symlink trick to connect to an executable.

Comment: @Rinzwind How would I go the virtualization path?

Comment: install virtuabox, install 1 or more Ubuntu (can also install diff. versions) in it. install 1 of each software in 1 of each Ubuntu. Might be overkill if it is a small program.

Comment: @Rinzwind a VM is too much. Is there any other way of virtualization that I can have 2 versions of the software? Maybe like a virtual drive or something.

Comment: @KingRetracted This answer provides three good answers to the asked question. If your question has...evolved, then please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1306263/edit) in order to solicit additional answers that you may like better. Comments on an answer are intended to help improve that answer, not for general dicusssion.